# configure nginx with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx

I am trying to configure nginx with wordpress.
the Apache server is running on **port 8083.**
the wordpress url is **https://dhahbya.com**

my nginx config file is :

```
server {
        listen *:443 ssl;

        server_name www.dhahbya.com dhahbya.com;

        ssl_certificate ****************;
        ssl_certificate_key **************;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8083;
        }
}
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name *.dhahbya.com;

     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

the issue is that when I try to navigate in the website it redirects me to 127.0.0.1:8083.

Comment: Try adding `proxy_set_header Host $host;` to your location block.

Comment: The page isn’t redirecting properly. the website is not giving response

Comment: If you got a redirect, that means you **are** receiving a response. A redirect response. What exactly redirect you got in response?

Comment: www.dhahbya.com the website is working as you can see it redirects to the ip address.
If I change the Site Address (URL) from the wordpress admin it no more works.

Comment: This isn't the answer I want. What is **exactly** the value of the `Location` HTTP header in the redirect response, including the HTTP scheme and the URI after the `IP:port` pair?

Comment: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 22 Jun 2022 17:27:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Redirect-By: WordPress
Location: https://www.dhahbya.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the work around was to remove the apache server and configure nginx to run wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

According to redirect responce you [showed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72717679/configure-nginx-with-wordpress?noredirect=1#comment128448138_72717679) in comments (please, use [markdown formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) in the future to post such a things):

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 22 Jun 2022 17:27:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Redirect-By: WordPress
Location: https://www.dhahbya.com/
```

This redirect is coming from the WordPress core, and the most probable reason is that WordPress can't detect the original request was made using the HTTPS protocol. Usually such problems are solved using the `X-Forwarded-...` HTTP headers:

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8083;
}
```

However for some unknown reasons WordPress didn't try to detect original request scheme using the non-standard yet widely used [`X-Forwarded-Proto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto) HTTP header, the [`is_ssl()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/fb93f0ecc1cd8b318a4ed6c46da62eb8d2afa332/wp-includes/load.php#L1412) WordPress function looks like the following (at the time this being written):

```php
function is_ssl() {
    if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
        if ( 'on' === strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
            return true;
        }

        if ( '1' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) {
            return true;
        }
    } elseif ( isset( $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) && ( '443' == $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The very common solution is to add this functionality to the `wp-config.php` file by yourself:

```php
if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] ) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
```

However I didn't like it since the same can be achieved without making changes to the WordPress files. If your upstream is an apache server using `mod_php` module, you can set that `HTTPS` variable from the apache configuration the following way:

```
<IfModule setenvif_module>
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto "^https$" HTTPS=on
</IfModule>
```

And if you serve WordPress by your upstream with another nginx instance via PHP-FPM, you can make that instance setting the `HTTPS` FastCGI variable with the `fastcgi_param` directive according to the `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP header value:

```
map $http_x_forwarded_proto $forwarded_https {
    https  on;
}

server {
    ...
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS $forwarded_https if_not_empty;
        ...
    }
}
```